# Bolding specific text in table with list of records

Tags: visualforce, javascript, pageblocktable, search

I have been working on creating a custom advanced visualforce search page for my users.  It's currently working well, but I was wondering if there was a way to bold specific words that get output into a table (containing records).  For example, I have a text box where users can start typing in a record name.  There is a table that updates dynamically (using javascript) showing all the records found from a query using the text entered into the text box.

Is there a way that I could bold the exact text value in each record name cell so that just the part of the text that was searched for could be in bold?  Ex: search for "new" would cause a record name of "Newsworthy" to show up but with just the "New" part in bold.  I think this could help users identify the record they are looking for.

Thanks!

Here is the snippet of my code that might be useful to see:

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var oldG;
            var oldAP;
            var oldAC;

            var delay = (function () {
                var timer = 0;
                return function (callback, ms) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
            })();

            function doSearch() {


                if (document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value == '' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value == '__' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value != oldG) {
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value = '';
                }

                if (document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value == '' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value == '__' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value != oldAP) {
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value = '';
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value = '';
                }

                if (document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value == '' ||     document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value == '__' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value != oldAC) {
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value = '';
                }

                oldG = document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value;
                oldAP = document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value;
                oldAC = document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value;


                searchServer(
                document.getElementById("Name").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value,
                document.getElementById("account").value,
                document.getElementById("agmtnumber").value);

            }

            function doClear() {


                document.getElementById("account").value = '';
                document.getElementById("Name").value = '';
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value = '';
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value = '';
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value = '';
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value = '';
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value = '';
                document.getElementById("account").value = '';
                document.getElementById("agmtnumber").value = '';

                searchServer(
                document.getElementById("Name").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtType}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value,
                document.getElementById("account").value,
                document.getElementById("agmtnumber").value);

            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input').keyup(function () {
                    delay(function () {

                        doSearch();

                    }, 700);
                });
            }); 

            var src_str = $("#nameoutput").html();
            var term = "Name";
            term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
            var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

            src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
            src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

            $("#nameoutput").html(src_str);

          </script> 

          <div style="position: relative;">
                <apex:outputpanel >
                    <apex:actionstatus id="status">
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                            <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb;
                                   height: 100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;"> 
                                <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 74.2px; width: 91px;">
                                    <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                                    <span class="waitingDescription">Loading...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionstatus>
                </apex:outputpanel>
             </div> 


          <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" status="loadStatus" rerender="results,debug,errors">
              <apex:param name="Name" value="" />
              <apex:param name="agmtPurpose" value="" />
              <apex:param name="agmtCategory" value="" />
              <apex:param name="agmtType" value="" />          
              <apex:param name="geography" value="" />
              <apex:param name="subgeography" value="" />
              <apex:param name="account" value="" />
              <apex:param name="agmtnumber" value="" />
          </apex:actionFunction>



          <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

              <apex:outputText Value="Limit to my agreements" style="text-align:center" > 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allOrMyAgmt}" title="Requestor or Owner" onchange="doSearch(), doMyOrAllAgmts()" id="allOrMy" />
              </apex:outputText>
              <br/>
              <br/>

          <tr>
              <td  style="font-weight:bold;" >Agreement Name<br/>
            <input type="text" id="Name" /><br/><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
             <td style="font-weight:bold;" >Account Name<br/>
            <input type="text" id="account"  /><br/><br/>
            </td>                  
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;" >Agreement Number<br/>
            <input type="text" id="agmtnumber"  /><br/><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>

           <tr>
               <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Purpose<br/>  
                <apex:inputfield id="agmtPurpose" value="{!agmt1.Nike_SF_Contract_Category__c}" onchange="doSearch();" > 

                   </apex:inputfield><br/><br/>
               </td>
          </tr>   
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Category<br/>  
            <apex:inputfield id="agmtCategory" value="{!agmt1.Apttus__Agreement_Category__c}"  onchange="doSearch();" > 

                </apex:inputfield><br/><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Type<br/>  
            <apex:inputfield id="agmtType" value="{!agmt1.NikeSF_Agreement_Type__c}"  onchange="doSearch();" > 

                </apex:inputfield><br/><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>    
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">Geography<br/>
              <apex:inputfield id="geography" value="{!agmt1.NikeSF_Geography__c}" onchange="doSearch();" >  

                  </apex:inputfield><br/><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">Sub-Geography<br/>
              <apex:inputfield id="subgeography" value="{!agmt1.NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c}" onchange="doSearch();" > 

                  </apex:inputfield>
            </td>
          </tr>
              <apex:outputText Value="Hide Filters" style="text-align:center" > 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!hideFilts}" title="Hide all filters" onchange="doHideFilters()" id="hideFilt" />
              </apex:outputText>
              <br/>
              <br/>
          </table>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
              <apex:commandButton style="text-align:center" onClick="doClear()" title="Clear" value="Clear" rerender="results,debug,errors"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          </apex:pageBlock>

        </td>
        <td valign="top">

        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">


            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
               <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons">

                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Beginning}" title="Beginning" value="<<" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="<Previous" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>        
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value="Next>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>
                   <br/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                    <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons2">
                        <apex:outputlabel style="text-align:center" value="Showing Page #{!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!Beginning}" title="Beginning" value="<<" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="<Previous" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>        
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value="Next>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" oncomplete="doSearch()"/>                  
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!agmts}" var="agmt">


               <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Agreement Name " status="loadStatus" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug" style="{!IF(sortValue=='Name', 'font-style: italic', 'font-style: normal')}">
                            <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!sortValue=='Name' && sortDir=='desc'}">&#x25B2;</apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!sortValue=='Name' && sortDir!='desc'}">&#x25BC;</apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            <apex:param name="sortValue" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortValue}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                   <div id='nameoutput' >
                   <apex:outputLink value="/{!agmt.id}">{!agmt.Name}</apex:outputLink>    
                   </div>

                </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a Visualforce specific way to do this, but you could use html and a javascript library like jquery's [Hightlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) plugin.

Here is an [example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery) from another StackExchange question that you could use as a starting point.

Comment: Hey JimRae, I am having difficulty getting this to work when I copied over the code from the example.  I pasted a snippet of my code in my question above.  All I was trying to do is highlight the field output value where text = name as a test.  Eventually I'd like to tie the value to what text is typed into the input (id=Name) field.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you download the plugin as a static resource, and are you including it on your page? And where are you calling the highlight method in your javascript?  You should have something like this `$("h1").highlight("highlight");` somewhere in your doSearch() method.